# Find the point where the slope changes drastically

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I have a distribution for which I have to find the point where the slope changes drastically. In visual terms, I have to find this point:

[image]

I though I could use derivatives, but for the following equation:

$$
y = -0.255ln(x) + 1.6889
$$

It seems I can't. How can I get what I need?

Comment: Without a definition of "changes drastically", it's difficult to interpret the question as "mathematics". :)

Comment: @user86418, I understand your point. :( I think it would correct to call it an [inflection points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point), but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Maybe what you want is maximum curvature.

Comment: @coffeemath it seems your right! I found [this one](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090205153743AAuYZGv), it seems the OP is asking for the same thing but I can't make sense out of the answer.

Comment: The displayed equation is not the one for the curve in the diagram. In the diagram, when $x=3$ it has $y=8.5,$ whereas putting $x=3$ into the formula gives $y=1.4087...$.

Comment: AnnoysParrot -- Just put up an answer hopefully showing how to get maximal curvature point. Still would like to know what actual formula matches the diagram curve.

Answer (score 2):

Let the curve be $y=-a \ln x +b.$ [The values of $a,b$ from the equation are then $a=0.255,\ b=1.6889,$ but note these values do not agree with the diagram in the question.]

Anyway it is not, for these curves, that one wants to maximize the second derivative, which here is $y''=a/x^2$ which goes to $+\infty$ as $x \to 0^+.$

The formula for curvature $\kappa(x)$ of the curve $y=y(x)$, when squared for ease of maximizing it, is
$$\kappa(x)^2=\frac{(y'')^2}{(1+y'^2)^3},$$
and when we take the derivative of this and insert $y'=-a/x, \ y''=a/x^2$ and factor, we get for the derivative of squared curvature the expression
$$\frac{-2a^2x(2x^2-a^2)}{(x^2+a^2)^4}.$$
So the maximal squared curvature (and thus the maximal curvature) occurs at $x=a/\sqrt{2}.$ For the values of $a,b$ noted at the top of this answer, taken from the displayed equation of the post, this gives the point of maximal curvature as about $(0.18031,2.12573).$ A more convincing thing would come if we knew the true values of $a,b$ for the equation which go with the diagram included in the question.